# curl_slist->next is never null so while loop gets stuck

Tags: c++, c++11, curl, cookies

I am working on a C++ library that does an API request using curl. I'm having an issue where I am trying to process the cookies that are returned in the response using `curl_slist` and `curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, &cookies);`.

It looks like its a linked list so I have a current and next attributes and I'm checking when next is NULL I should break out of the loop but for some reason its getting stuck in the loop, looks like its doing the same cookie over and over again but can't see why.

```
struct curl_slist* cookies;
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, &cookies);

int i = 1;
std::vector<CookieObj> cookieObjects;
struct curl_slist* current = cookies;
if (current != NULL)
{
    string cookieString = string(current->data);
    CookieObj cookieObj = storeCookie(cookieString);
    cookieObjects.push_back(cookieObj);

    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        string cookieString = string(current->data);
        CookieObj cookieObj = this->storeCookie(cookieString);
        cookieObjects.push_back(cookieObj);
        current = cookies->next;

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: How your current is updating in while loop ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the current variable is updated towards the end of the while loop to be what the value of `cookies->next` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
current = cookies->next
```

`cookies` always points to the same thing, so `cookies->next` will always point to the same thing. SO, yes, the loop will continue indefinitely (assuming there are at least 2 cookies in the list). You want instead:

```
current = current->next;
```

**code simplification**

Your current code also process the first cookie twice since current isn't updated until the end. One possible code rearrangement:

```
for (current=cookies; current; current=current->next) {
   /* process cookie */
}
```